# In MongoDB, insertOne is not returning the document object if executed via REST API. What is wrong?

Tags: php, mongodb, rest, api, return

I am using mongoDB with PHP. I would like to figure out why the insertOne function does not return the

```
$insertedDocument = $collection->insertOne($data)
```

even after successfully adding it to the collection on the server.

But, if used on a regular PHP page, the function does return the $insertedDocument (verified using var_dump).

Case 1:
1. A simple page with a PHP block that uses the
    $insertedDocument = $collection->insertOne($data).
2. Outputs the $insertedDocument correctly, and as expected.

Case 2:
1. Using Axios, when sending a POST request to https://domain.tld/namespace/endpoint/, $data is appended to the $body of the request.
2. $data is recieved as expected
3. When using the same function (copied and pasted it in a PHP block on a static page as is for debugging), $insertedDocument is null.
4. But, the data is successfully store on the server. Verified the data of the $insertedDocument in the $collection on the server.

```
try {
  $insertedDocument = $this->mdb_collection->insertOne(array(
    'key1' => $data1,
    'key2' => $data2,
    'key3' => $data3,
    'key4' => new UTCDateTime
  ));
} catch (Exception $e) {
  return new WP_Error('error-registering', __('There was an error while registering', 'domain'));
}

return $insertedDocument;
```

With the REST API, insertOne does not return anything, when the actual expected return value is the $insertedDocument.

Comment: You didn't return $insertedDocument. What is $document ?

Comment: @Jits, corrected the code.

Comment: Is it working ?

Comment: @Jits, I am afraid not. :-/

Comment: @Jits, thank you, it does get the ID. But the question still stands. Why is the behaviour different when called via the REST API?

Comment: $insertedDocument->getInsertedId() you will get id

Comment: You should  encode it before returning it wait I'll give you example

Comment: json_encode($insertedDocument, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Comment: Are you using laravel ?

Comment: @Jits, well, thank you! But, I won't be returning the ID. It is just to verify that the ID was successfully completed. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the following code to alter my workflow and complete it instead.

```
$insertedDocument->getInsertedId();
```

> Credit goes to Jits in the question's comments | https://stackoverflow.com/users/7585179/jits